# WPF - Load Image in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

i have a little problem with my WPF-Application.

Well, i have a ListView which shows at the first column a image. Each element can or cannot have a image, so from time to time i load a "default" image in this column.

Here is the problem.

When i load the default image, there is no image shown in the listview.

Here is the codepart, which adds the default image:

```
 Uri src = new Uri(@"/myapp;component/Images/Picture.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                        BitmapImage small_image_bmp = new BitmapImage();

                        small_image_bmp.BeginInit();
                        small_image_bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        small_image_bmp.UriSource = src;
                        small_image_bmp.EndInit();
                        small_image_bmp.Freeze();

                        dto.Bild1_Bitmap = small_image_bmp;               


                    this.liste.Add(dto);
```

This code is not working.

But this part **works very well**:

```
 Uri src = new Uri(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myapp\myapp\Images\Picture.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                        BitmapImage small_image_bmp = new BitmapImage();

                        small_image_bmp.BeginInit();
                        small_image_bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        small_image_bmp.UriSource = src;
                        small_image_bmp.EndInit();
                        small_image_bmp.Freeze();

                        dto.Bild1_Bitmap = small_image_bmp;               


                    this.liste.Add(dto);
```

As you can see, the part who isnt working has a relative path and the code, who is working, has a absolute path.

But of course i cant use the absolute path...

Here is the XAML of the ListViewColumn:

```
  <GridViewColumn Header="Bild">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Bild1_Bitmap}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

If code you posted for loading an image is in same assembly as of image. You can ignore component path and use like this - `Images\Picture.png`.

Also make sure `image build action` is set to `Resource`.

Comment: Unfortunatly it isnt working. Now my Uri looks like this: 
new Uri(@"Images/Picture.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
but i get the "DirectoryNotFound" Exception. It tries to load the following path: "C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myapp\myapp\bin\Debug\Images\Picture.png"

Comment: It has to be `Images\Picture.png`. Notice forward slash. And is it in same assembly or different?

Comment: Its the same assebly.

Comment: Tried with forward slash? And have you check build action is set as Resource and not Content?